# Contact section wont centralize

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Updated Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek5Eo.jpg) I have a problem I can't seem to centralize my contact information. Below is the code I have that pushes all the small logos with the text to the side of the webpage.
However, my final goal is to have them placed in one line. Any help is welcome!

```css
   .media {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: start;
        -ms-flex-align: start;
        align-items: flex-start
     }

.media-body {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1
}
```

```html
 <section class="contact-section">
         <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
            <div class="media contact-info">
                <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h3>Buttonwood, California.</h3>
                    <p>Rosewoodly, PA 750918</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media contact-info">
                <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-tablet"></i></span>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h3>+2 257 995 2885</h3>
                    <p>Mon to Fri 7am to 6pm</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media contact-info">
                <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h3>support@testemail.com</h3>
                    <p>Send us a message anytime!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Send an image of what you want to do, have a try `display: inline-block`

Comment: Hi Simasan. Unfortunately, your question is pretty unclear to me. However, if your goal is, to arrange the items in one horizontal row, I guess `flex-direction: row` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, sorry this is my first time posting or asking any questions really. But yes my objective is to line the elements in a horizontal row as well as their logo images.I have updated the post with an image of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using flexbox. If you want all children to be in one line.

Just wrap around one more div to all and give it `display:flex`

```
<section class="contact-section">
     <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
       <div class="media-wrapper">
         <div class="media contact-info"></div>
         <div class="media contact-info"></div>
         <div class="media contact-info"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and then add following css

```
.media-wrapper {
    display:flex;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ksilentstorm/pen/eYmeXvr

For knowledge purpose

Just adjust child elements by putting following lines in parent css that is .media-wrapper.

For **horizontal alignment** - `justify-content: center/flex-start/flex-end;`

For **vertical alignment** `align-items: center/flex-start/flex-end;`

For direction `flex-direction: row` or `flex-direction: column`

**Note: When direction changes justify-content and align-items both exchange its nature.**

For more info. you can visit.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: I did this, the elements did snap to a horizontal line. However, the text in them and the contact form for some reason turned in a column. Not at all aligned. Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please update the screenshot of current position?

Comment: Updated the screenshot, you can take a look.

Comment: Have you removed previously suggested solution by another user?

Comment: Yes :) that was done for each of the proposed solutions.

Comment: I have updated an answer, please visit that codepen link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.media {
  /* display: -webkit-box; */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 17px;
}

.media-body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact-section">
  <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
    <div class="media contact-info">
      <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h3>Buttonwood, California.</h3>
        <p>Rosewoodly, PA 750918</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media contact-info">
      <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-tablet"></i></span>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h3>+2 257 995 2885</h3>
        <p>Mon to Fri 7am to 6pm</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media contact-info">
      <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h3>support@testemail.com</h3>
        <p>Send us a message anytime!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Didn't work it lined up my items next to the contact form instead of them being on top of it in a horizontal row. :/

Comment: Alright do you have contact form as well in the same row?

Comment: My contact form is actually below in another <div>. Like this <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">. That's pretty much it, I don't know why it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Restructured your HTML code and styled using flex.Hope this helps you.

```
 <section>
     <div class="contact-section">
        <div class="address">
       <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h3>Buttonwood, California.</h3>
                <p>Rosewoodly, PA 750918</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contactInfo">
            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-tablet"></i></span>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h3>+2 257 995 2885</h3>
                <p>Mon to Fri 7am to 6pm</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
            <span class="contact-info__icon"><i class="ti-email"></i></span>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h3>support@testemail.com</h3>
                <p>Send us a message anytime!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css change

```
.contact-section{ display:flex;}
```